# How to create a page listing Schema.org news

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

As Schema.org
"`https://example.com/news`"

I have a page called card and in this page there are photos, title and short description of the news as card, there is also a read more button. There are more than one news card on this page, how should I create a Schema.org JSON-LD for this.

I don't understand, should I create all of them as new articles?